# Ubuntu & Plesk - How to exclude a sub-url from password protection?

Tags: ubuntu, password, plesk, apache-virtualhost

I have website which is password protected where runs a php app on it. Now I have to unprotect a sub-url of that website but without disablng the protection of the main site which is configured through plesk. This sub-url is given by the php app and is not a physical folder. Any hints how I can achieve that?

OS  Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Webserver Apache2 
Plesk Version   12.0.18

How do I find where plesk is storing/managing the "RequireUser" directives for my website?  I assuming it is writing in somewhere into a vhost.conf? Or does plesk uses a different approach to manage password protected directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my problem by using a ".htaccess" file on my website which then excludes the url. This brings the benefit that I do not have to change anything which is managed by Plesk. The example is valid for apache 2.4 for older version you need to change it accordingly.

```
# Allow access to excluded diretories
SetEnvIf Request_URI /shop/api  noauth=1
<RequireAny>
  Require env noauth
  Require env REDIRECT_noauth
  Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```